# MacBook Pro having issues with the battery and the trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, trackpad

So my mom has a MacBook Pro A1502 and the trackpad was having some issues so I took out the battery to see if it was something with the cable. When I powered back on the computer the trackpad was working except that when I clicked on something it wouldn't register. Basically the cursor moved but when I clicked on something nothing happened. So, thinking it was a glitch I unplugged the battery and plugged back in again. Same result. Then I took the battery out to double check that the cable was all good and when I plugged it back in it won't start up.

Do I need to just replace the battery or did I unwittingly mess things up big time?

Comment: What if you connect it to the mains (AC) power?

Comment: The light on the charger goes green for a second then turns orange.

Comment: Can you power it up?

Comment: No I can't for some reason. Thats the  issue.

Comment: Then you likely blew out one or more of the components on the power rail(s).  It needs to go in for service.